# Symfony 3 doesn't authenticate user from database

Tags: php, security, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm learning Symfony at the moment and have a problem with authentication of users that are stored in a database. I have followed the Tutorials from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) but I always receive an "invalid credentials" error. Here comes my code so far (sorry for the names but this is what the "customer" wants).

security.yml:

```
security:

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\Benutzer:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    mysql_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:Benutzer
            property: bNID
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          login_path: login
          check_path: login
          require_previous_session: false
          default_target_path: /auth/bnme
        provider: mysql_provider
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

This is how I load my user into the database

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\Controller;

 use AppBundle\Entity\Benutzer;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class UserController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * @Route("/user", name="user")
 */

public function createAction(){

    //Get Entity Object
    $user = new Benutzer();

    //Encrypt password

    $plainpw = 'Initial-PW-55218';
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
    $pwd = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainpw);

    //Set Entity fields     
    $user->setANREDE("Herr");
    $user->setBNID("GPUCS@web.de");
    $user->setINIPW($pwd);
    $user->setBNTYP("SA");
    $user->setKOEPID(1);
    $user->setNACHNAME("KomBau-System");
    $user->setVORNAME("UL");

    //get Entity Manager
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //write Entity in database
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Created user with id: '.$user->getBNID());
}
}
```

and this is my loginAction:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $system = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:System')->find(1);

    return $this->render('default/sstm.html.twig', array('error' => $error, 'system' => $system));
}
```

The login with users that are hard coded into security.yml works. But this is not what is wanted by the customer. Can somebody help me with this?

This is the entity class for the user. I left the getters and setters away due to the length of the code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Benutzer_TAB")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 * This class represents database table Benutzer_TAB which holds user informations
 */
class Benutzer implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="KOEPID", type="integer", length=8)
 */

private $kOEPID;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="BNID", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @ORM\id
 *
 * User-ID as email adress
 */
private $bNID;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="BNTYP", type="string", length=2)
 *
 * Usertype (Systemadmin or normal user)
 */
private $bNTYP;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ANREDE", type="string", length=4)
 */
private $aNREDE;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="VORNAME", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $vORNAME;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NACHNAME", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nACHNAME;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="INIPW", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $iNIPW;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="BNPW", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $bNPW;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getRoles()
 */
public function getRoles() {
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getPassword()
 */
public function getPassword() {
    if(!$this->getBNPW()){
        $this->getINIPW();
    } else {
        $this->getBNPW();
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getSalt()
 */
public function getSalt() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername()
 */
public function getUsername() {
    $this->getBNID();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::eraseCredentials()
 */
public function eraseCredentials() {
    // TODO: Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Serializable::serialize()
 */
public function serialize() {
    return serialize(array(
            $this->kOEPID,
            $this->bNID,
            $this->iNIPW,
    ));
}

/**
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * @see Serializable::unserialize()
 */
public function unserialize($serialized) {
    list(
        $this->kOEPID,
        $this->bNID,
        $this->iNIPW,) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it! And the mistake I made is so severe, that I lightheartedly will give all my reputationpoints away. For I don't deserve them. This is the code of my getPassword() function in the user entity as it was:

```
public function getPassword() {
if(!$this->getBNPW()){
    $this->getINIPW();
} else {
    $this->getBNPW();
}
}
```

and this is how it should look like:

```
public function getPassword() {
if(!$this->getBNPW()){
    return $this->getINIPW();
} else {
    return $this->getBNPW();
}
}
```

I will throw it all away and work with wood or something like that.....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the entity,

Why in your firewall your provider is comment ?
You should have:

```
 default:
    anonymous: ~
    form_login:
      provider: mysql_provider
      login_path: login
      check_path: login
      require_previous_session: false
      default_target_path: /auth/bnme
```

Comment: Yes it was a little mistake. See the comment above

Comment: the provider should be under form_login to work no ?

Comment: Well, that actually changed the error message. I take this as a good sign. Now it says "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."

Comment: Yes :)
 You can check the logs to see what sort of system problem is it ?

Comment: Your database is up to date ?    doctrine:schema:update

Comment: Yes, database is up to date. The Log shows me an AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): Class AppBundle\\Entity\\User does not exist at...
It seems like I have the wrong naming somewhere

Comment: Ah crap. I found it, solved it, and there it is again: Invalid Credentials.
Is it possible, that the encryption of the encoder_factory does not match the encryption of the login-form? When I encrpyt the hardcoded Password in security.yml it is different from that which is saved in the database.

Comment: nope. Expected known_string to be a string, NULL given. And I think I have an idea. The field in the entity which holds the password is called iNIPW via customer convention. I don't think, that Symfony finds this... I havn't thought about that. I will check where I can fix that.

Comment: Maybe check the getSalt(), you put "return null" maybe you need to add [$this->salt = ""] in __construct and [return $this->salt;] in getSalt().

Comment: Is this really needed? The documentation says that when I use bcrypt the salt is added automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107725/discussion-between-lemairep-and-raistlin).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing mysql_provider to default_provider; also check that your User (Benutzer) entity implements the UserInterface. Using a custom repository for loading the user doesn't hurt, but it should not be a solution to your problem.

Also, in my code, I am encoding passwords with EncoderFactory::getEncoder(User) from the service 'security.encoder_factory'. That might be where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. I still have the same result.